# Ruby check if record exists and associations in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

Something I always run in to. I want to do this:

```
if current_user.exists? && current_user.role == "admin"
  # Do something
end
```

Obviously if current user does not exist then this does not work as it returns `undefined method role for nil class`

Is there a way I can achieve the above in one line without multiple If statements?

Comment: Since you want to check _"if record exists **and** associations"_, you might want to try `&&` instead of `||` :-)

Comment: Ah yes .. I guess I'm asking about both but good catch I'll update

Comment: The right-hand sided of `&&` isn't evaluated if the left-hand side is `nil` or `false`. So `current_user.role` is only called if the first condition passes, i.e. if the user exists. The exception won't occur in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
if current_user&.role == "admin"
```

`&` is a safe navigator - if the part before it is nil, the rest of the method chain won't execute and simply returns nil rather than throwing an error.

More reading: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: _"the rest of the method chain won't execute"_ – it would still execute `nil == "admin"` which is also `false` but for a different reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use traditional `.try`

`current_user.try(:role) == "admin"`

or safe navigation operator for which is faster `&.` if you're using ruby `>= 2.3.0`

`current_user&.role == "admin"`